# how is evals's execution context different than that of functional execution context in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> Execution context in JavaScript are of three types:

**Global execution context (GEC):** This is the default execution context in which JS code start it’s execution when the file first loads in the browser. All the global code are executed inside global execution context. In the browser context, if the code is executing in strict mode value of this is undefined else it is window object. Global execution context cannot be more than one because only one global environment is possible for JS code execution.
**Functional execution context (FEC):** Functional execution context is defined as the context created by the execution of code inside a function. Each function has it’s own execution context. It can be more than one. Functional execution context have access to all the code of global execution context. While executing global execution context code, if JS engine finds a function call, it creates a new functional execution context for that function.
**Eval:** Execution context inside eval function.

Comment: Where is this quoted from?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/execution-context-in-javascript-319dd72e8e2c